# pygame.display.set_mode() too slow with threading (up to 18 seconds)

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I want to use pygame drawing/event handling in its separate thread, while leaving the main thread for all computations.

Here is a minimal working example. Everything works as intended, after initialization the performance is fine. But the `self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([400, 400])` line takes 18 seconds to execute.

```
import threading
import time
import pygame


class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = None
        self.gui_thread = None
        self.gui_initialized = False
        self.keep_running_gui_thread = True

        self.gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._gui_loop)
        self.gui_thread.start()
        while not self.gui_initialized:
            pass  # await gui initialization

    def _gui_loop(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode([400, 400])
        self.gui_initialized = True

        while self.keep_running_gui_thread:
            ...  # handle events etc.

        pygame.quit()

    def close(self):
        self.keep_running_gui_thread = False
        self.gui_thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tick = time.perf_counter()
    window = Window()
    print(f"init: {time.perf_counter() - tick} seconds")
    window.close()
```

What's even weirder is that when I try to run it with Scalene it starts to run much faster: the loading time is reduced from 18 to 1-2 seconds.

Regarding the core design:

1. I want to run it using multithreading/multiprocessing etc. for smooth gui without redesigning my computation-heavy application around pygame from the very beginning.
2. I want to run pygame-related stuff in the secondary thread (not the main one) so that my computation-heavy application controls (creates/manages) the gui and not vice-versa.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. Apparently

```
while not self.gui_initialized:
    pass
```

is really bad because it causes a nearly complete freeze on all threads due to GIL.
Simply adding a time.sleep(0.1) inside the loop fixes the problem.